# Introdução de fórmulas na aplicação Web

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Saudações!
Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Web, com as ferramentas (HTML+CSS+JAVASCRIPT){BootStrap}+PHP+MySQL.
É uma espécie de cadernenta do professor, e em algum momento o professor terá que introduzir a fórmula do cálculo da média de frequência por exemplo. Com base na fórmula que o prof for introduzir, precisarei gerar uma tabela onde será exibida a nota do estudante em cada uma das variáveis introduzidas na fórmula.

Exemplo:
Sendo a fórmula: Mf = T1(25%) + T2(25%) + TG(35%) + AC(15%);
onde: Mf -> média de freqência;
T1 -> Teste1;
T2 -> Trabalho em grupo;
AC -> Ava;iação contínua;

A questão é que estou procurando uma maneira o utilizador introduzir a fórmula da forma mais simples possível. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer algo mais ou menos nesse sentido.

```
<div id="inputs">

</div>
<script>
    let z = document.createElement("INPUT");
    z.setAttribute("type", "text");
    z.setAttribute("name", "t1");
    z.setAttribute("id", "t1");
    document.getElementById('inputs').append(z);
</script>
```

Para criar os campos em tela com a quantidade de notas que o professor informar.

Comment: Agradeço, ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

A maneira mais fácil:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <form action="/inserirnotas.php">
        MF: <input type="text" name="media><br>
        T1: <input type="text" name="t1"><br>
        T2: <input type="text" name="t2"><br>
        AC: <input type="text" name="ac"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submeter">
        </form>
        <?php
        $calculo = $_POST['media']*0.25 + $_POST['t1'](25%) + $_POST['t2']*0.35 + $_POST['ac']*0.15;
        echo $calculo;
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: obrigado!, consegui ter ideia do que devo fazer.